# Host File and Virtual Servers

Tags: windows, host, virtual-server

I have WAMP installed on my Windows Computer.

I want to set up a few virtual servers, on the following addresses:

```
127.0.0.1 to localhost/website1/
127.0.0.2 to localhost/website2/
```

Here's the contents of my host file:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost/website1
127.0.0.2 localhost/website2
```

But none of them seem to work.  Both addresses just lead me to the localhost ROOT.

If I visit http://localhost/website1 or http://localhost/website2 they both work.

Am I doing something wrong?

I'm completely flexible with the IP addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your virtual hosts to **httpd-vhosts.conf** (of apache server, it is located inside a folder like this wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\conf\extra)
Example for adding virtual host is in that file.
and you also may need to uncomment(remove # sign) from following line in your **httpd.conf** file

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Is this as well as what I have in my hosts file?

Comment: Yes, You need to update your hosts file too in addition to do this. I don't know what is the machine of IP 127.0.0.2. I usually define virtual hosts in httpd-vhosts.conf as mentioned above, then match those virtual host web addresses to my local machine IP, 127.0.0.1. Let say you have a virtual host named "mywebiste1", then you need to add "127.0.0.1 mywebsite1" to your hosts file.